# Javascript How to not to use global variables when creating arrays to access from different functions

Tags: javascript, parsing, scope, callback

I read some data with Papa Parse, and I callback the result to `unpack`. I want to be able to use the created arrays in other functions. (something like `console.log(unpack(data))` outside `unpack`.

How do I call the arrays?

```
//read data from csv 
function parseData(file, callback) {
    Papa.parse(file, {
        download: true,
        complete: function(results) {           
            callback(results.data);
        }
    });
}

// want to use the created arrays in other functions.
function unpack(data) {
    var locations = [];
    var bsis = [];
    var lngs = [];
    var lats = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        locations.push(data[i][2]);
        bsis.push(data[i][3]);
        lats.push(data[i][4]);
        lngs.push(data[i][5]);
    }
    return [locations, bsis, lats, lngs];
}
```

I call it with

```
parseData("data/Runs/csvs/csvs_with_latlon/ShelterRun1.csv", unpack);
```

Comment: `parseData("…", function(data) { const result = unpack(data); console.log("outside of unpack:", result); })`

Answer (score 0):

When you have callbacks, you'll need to deal with it at that point.

If you don't want to use a global, you'll just have to nest the functions indefinitely:

```js
const A = (a, callback) => callback(a+5)
const B = (r, callback) => callback(r + 5);

A(5, (r) => B(r, console.log))
```

There isn't a way to just return it out of callbacks.

That said, you don't have to have it truly top-level global. It can be a "global" inside of another function:

```js
const A = (a, callback) => callback(a+5)
const B = (r, callback) => callback(r+5)

const run = () => {
  let result;
  
  A(5, r => B(r, r => { result = r }));
  
  setTimeout(() => console.log(result), 50);
}

run()
```

That said, because callbacks are an async pattern, you can't force an async to be synchronous, so to use the global outside of the callbacks, you'd still have to have some kind of wait or other async pattern to check for the result.

Comment: Using outer-scope variables is a horrible idea and leads to race conditions

Comment: Indeed. I do not recommend it for most things. If you are using async, you need to stick with async. But it can be a viable pattern with things like React or Angular, where they just render whatever is available and you have different sets of async and it doesn't matter if when it switches from null to not.